# Retrofit2 and OkHttp3 single request interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Starting with OkHttp v3 OkHttpClient is immutable and so is the interceptor's list.

Starting with Retrofit 2.0-beta3 it depends on OkHttp v3.

In my app I need to parse Google Analytics Campain refferer key, which has "a=1&b=2&c=3" format, and append it to sign up request URL.

With previous version of retrofit it was easy to do by adding

```
retrofit.client().interceptors().add(0, chain -> {
    final Request httpRequest = chain.request();
    return chain.proceed(httpRequest.newBuilder().url(httpRequest.httpUrl().toString() + "&" + request.getUtmParams()).build());
});
```

before executing call and

```
retrofit.client().interceptors().remove(0);
```

after call is proceed.

Can't figure out how to achieve the same behaviour with the new version.
Please help.

UPD 1. The goal is to control request URL of single request. Appending string to the end is just an example. Using @QueryMap is an option, but it requires parsing parameter string which I try to avoid.

Comment: OkHttp `Interceptor`s didn't much changed. Parsing utm from url is easy with uri utils.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the interceptor once and then use a header to trigger the interceptor. See [this post](https://publicobject.com/2016/01/17/sneaking-data-into-an-okhttp-interceptor/) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Use query map.

```
public interface ApiService {
@GET("YOUR_BASE_URL")
Call<Login> authenticate(@Query("a") String a, @Query("b") String b,@Query("c") String c);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your request Method but here I am using GET

// You can also use a Map Query to acheive the same result

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("api/{a}/{b}/{c}")
    Call<Login> authenticate(@Path("a") String a, @Path("b") String password, @Path("c") String c);
}
```

**Create a EntityObject**

```
public EntityObject {

   Public String a;

   Public String b;

   Public String c;
}
```

Use the retrofit to make your request with your parameters

```
private void makeRemoteRequest(String a, String b, String c){

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

 ApiInterface mService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

Call<Login> mService = mService.authenticate(a, b, c);
    mService.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, It can be done with QueryMap, but it requires parsing "utm_params" string (split by "&" and then by "=") and I want to avoid this.

Comment: The goal is to control request URL of single request.
Appending string to the end is just an example.